# Let $a, b, c, d, e, f$ be nonnegative real numbers...

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a, b, c, d, e, f$ be nonnegative real numbers such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + d^2 + e^2 + f^2 = 6$ and $ab + cd + ef = 3$. What is the maximum value of $a+b+c+d+e+f$?

I need help proving that $a+b+c+d+e+f \leq 6$

Answer (score 2):

Multiply the second equation by $2$, add to the first equation and complete the squares
\begin{eqnarray*}
(a+b)^2+(c+d)^2+(e+f)^2=12.
\end{eqnarray*}
Let $A=a+b$,$B=c+d$ and $C=e+f$. Now use RMS-AM inequality
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sqrt{ \frac{A^2+B^2+C^2}{3}} \geq \frac{A+B+C}{3}.
\end{eqnarray*}